# Polymer+Firebase Element - Show spinner while updating data

Tags: firebase, spinner, polymer

I'm trying to learn Polymer, but I have some questions and can't find the solutions anywhere.

I want to put a loading spinner in my app, while the data is being retrieved from firebase (using firebase-element) to fill the screen info. How can I detect that all data/elements are already loaded in light DOM, so I can hide the spinner?

I know there is a polymer-ready event, but it doesn't take in count the firebase-element data, or I guess so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase-element has a dataReady property that specifies if a location's data has been loaded at least once.